# Who inherited the rights to Otis Blackwell's extensive song library?

Tags: history, rock

I've been reading about Otis Blackwell's life, and I noticed that no one mentioned an [Otis Blackwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otis_Blackwell) estate or inheritors. So I'm wondering - who, if anyone, inherited rights to / his share of royalties for the songs he wrote?